# Django, How to display Bid History made on that listing

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

How can I display only the history of Bids for each specific listing?
Right now my page shows all the Bids history no matter for what listing on the website

Models.py

```
class AuctionListing(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.TextField()
start_bid = models.IntegerField(null=True)
image = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
seller = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Default_Value")

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.title} listing | {self.seller}"

class Bid(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_bids")
listing = models.ForeignKey(AuctionListing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
bid_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.user} put a bid in for {self.price}"
```

Views.py

```
def view_bids(request, product_id):
    return render(request, "auctions/view_bids.html")
```

view_bids.html

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block title %} Item Bid History {% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="thumbnail text-center">
            <h4>Bid History</h4>
                {% for user in user.user_bids.all %}
                    <strong>
                        {{user.user}} -
                        {{user.price}}$ -
                        {{user.bid_time}}
                    </strong>
            <br>
                {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Plenty of issues here, not the least of which: Cascading deletion of bids on user deletion is almost certainly not a good idea, these models can result in simultaneous bids on the same listing, you appear to be iterating over a single user's bids and referring to each bid as `user`, and you're not actually passing any context into the view that would tell it which product (this should probably be _listing_ unless you have multiple listings per product) to use. I think the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/#first-steps) would be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks for the note about the Cascading, True I have updated views to pass an object and the template and now it works

Answer (score 0):

Views.py - updated

```
def view_bids(request, product_id):
product = AuctionListing.objects.get(id=product_id)
return render(request, "auctions/view_bids.html", {
    'product': product
})
```

Template - update

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block title %} Item Bid History {% endblock %}
{% block body %}

<div class="thumbnail text-center">
    <h4>Bid History</h4>
    <div class="row">
            {% for bid in product.listing_bids.all %}
                <div class="column">
                    <h6><strong>Bidder</strong></h6>
                    <p>{{bid.user}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <h6><strong>Bid Amount</strong></h6>
                    <p>{{bid.price}}$</p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <h6><strong>Bid Time</strong></h6>
                    <p>{{bid.bid_time}}</p>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```